# User asking exercises from textbook without so identifying

Tags: discussion, homework, citation

A user is copying verbatim exercises from [my textbook](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/DCG/), e.g.,
[Local Feature Size](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475996/local-feature-size), [Describe Conv(A U B)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475854/describe-convab),
[Flip graph of point set](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/475172/237),
[Expected number on the convex hull](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/474963/237), etc. Is the MSE convention that he should identify the questions as homework, and perhaps even identify the source when copying verbatim?

I am not a regular reader of MSE meta, so my apologies if this has been well-hashed earlier.

Comment: This is a somewhat contentious issue, but generally the homework tag is treated as an honor system, i.e. it should not be added unless the user says the question is homework. For example, the user could be self-studying.

Comment: @AlexBecker: Good point that the user could be self-studying; that didn't occur to me. Nevertheless, I found it a bit jarring to see my own words posted in problems without attribution. I would classify it as a form a plagiarism.

Comment: @Alex: It seems to me slightly different from an honor system. The question is whether or not when copying a question *verbatim* from a book, should one give a citation or not? I believe that one should at least mention the book's name (not only for full disclosure, but also to help the answerers understand what the OP knows, or doesn't, about the question).

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke. I agree. If it were a question from one of my books, I'd feel the same way. From a copyright point one *might* argue that it falls under fair use, though the lack of citation would almost certainly be actionable under the copyright holder's right of attribution. This is likely a moot point, though, unless you, rather than the publisher, held the copyright.

Comment: I agree with [Will Jagy](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/10400/will-jagy): "If people would include the source of a given problem as part of the process of posting a question, life would be a little easier."  I don't care much about the homework tag, but I do wish sources would be included for copied (or paraphrased) problems.

Comment: @AsafKaragila. Though it has nothing to do with this post, you're on my s***t list for getting me sucked into SMBC earlier today. Thanks for wasting an hour of my time.

Comment: @Rick: You're welcome! :-D

Comment: It may be a good idea to have, as part of the instructions for site use, a request for acknowledgement of sources. That request will probably end up being widely ignored, and I would not be in favour of stringent enforcement. However, a statement of standards has value.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I was specifically addressing the tagging as homework; the plagiarism question completely slipped my mind. I agree that attribution is important.

Comment: Related discussions: [Require proper citation for verbatim quoted questions, answers, proofs?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/656/require-proper-citation-for-verbatim-quoted-questions-answers-proofs),
[Texts that are verbatim copied from somewhere else](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/596/texts-that-are-verbatim-copied-from-somewhere-else) and
[Centralized solutions to textbook problems considered harmful?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9142/centralized-solutions-to-textbook-problems-considered-harmful/)

Comment: It would certainly be helpful to identify the source, and most would, I think, regard it as good manners, but the idea that quoting textbook exercises here without attribution is plagiarism strikes me as absurd.

Comment: @Brian, that is the second time I agree with you. But I don't feel that it's something we need to encourage strongly and even by issuing warnings and/or suspensions to users which copy verbatim questions from books with attribution.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Which features of plagiarism are lacking from the case at hand, which make that you do not see it as such?

Comment: @Asaf: I don’t think that we should go that far, but I can agree with André’s comment.

Comment: @Did: I don’t see that the question even arises. The people who post such questions are obviously not claiming authorship.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott This might be more a problem of *copyright* then, regarding the right of attribution.

Comment: Three points. First, I personally do not care much about copyright, so even if there is a violation, that's not an issue to me. Second, plagiarism is "taking someone else's work or ideas and passing them off as one's own." When we upvote someone's rep for a question, we are in some sense congratulating the OP for the clarity of the question, its mathematical content, its potential usefulness to others. The OP is "passing off" the question as their own and accruing rep for "someone else's work." Third, I feel personally violated, which I take as a sign that it *is* a form of plagiarism.

Comment: When I upvote a question, I am congratulating the poster for her good taste.

Comment: @zyx: Good point! I will try to let flattery outweigh insult. :-) Still, never, ever would I quote someone verbatim without quotes and a reference.

Comment: @Joseph: I’m not disputing your feelings, but I really don’t see any legitimate reason for you to feel violated. The interpretation that the OP is passing off your work for his or her own strikes me as implausible in the extreme, and upvotes on questions have all sorts of different meanings depending on the voter. I, for example, rarely upvote for any of the reasons that you mention, but rather for commentary of various sorts added to the basic question. If anything, it seems to me that you should be pleased that someone is using a book of yours!

Comment: @Brian: Do you ever quote *anyone* **verbatim** without attribution? In your papers, in your MSE posts, even in private emails? I presume not!

Comment: @Joseph: I expect that I’ve probably used some routine textbook exercises verbatim or nearly so without attribution on some of my exams. In the case of a textbook exercise I fail to see what difference it makes whether the exercise is quoted verbatim or paraphrased. There are exceptions, especially in the case of carefully designed multi-part exercises at an advanced level, but most exercises are variations on themes in the common intellectual pool; claiming any special ownership on the basis of a specific variant or wording is silly. But all of this is really beside the point: ...

Comment: ... whether an exercise posted to MSE as a question is quoted verbatim or not, the poster is obviously not claiming any sort of intellectual property rights or making any claim to originality. The situation is not in the least comparable to quoting one paper in another, or one answer here in another.

Comment: I asked a question on Academia StackExchange about [citing sources of problems in assignments](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/1744/64).  You might want to look at the answers there.

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/769/12357

Comment: What are the rules regarding homework questions? Do we have to use the homework tag when asking a question assigned as homework?